# Why does link order affect the test result of a test that uses macros?

Tags: c++, linker, c-preprocessor, googletest, googlemock

I'm using Google Test and Google Mock to write code using Test Driven Development. I'm writing a small "plugin" for Google Test. To make sure the tests would fail when expected with the correct message, I created a simple `FailureReporter` class that I would sub-class and inject a mock version in the plugin to capture the results and compare with expected values.

In the spirit of TDD extremism, I also wrote a test to make sure the `FailureReporter` worked. To do this, I "replaced" the `FAIL()` macro in order to not cause a failure but to capture the resulting error message. However, this is where things became strange. It was working on one machine but not on another. While searching for the cause I discovered that it could be fixed by changing the link order. This seems strange, because the "fix" is done using macros, and I would assume that it would be hard coded at compile time, and linking it wouldn't make a difference.

What I found out was that: linking the test by itself causes no problems. Linking it with a test that uses the mock version of FailureReporter only works if the other test is linked after the `FailureReporterTest.` Why does this happen?

FailureReporter.hpp:

```
#ifndef FAILURE_REPORTER_H
#define FAILURE_REPORTER_H

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class FailureReporter {
public:
    virtual void fail(const char* errorMessage) {
        FAIL() << errorMessage;
    }
};

#endif
```

FailureReporterTest.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

static std::stringstream* failStream;

#ifdef FAIL
#undef FAIL
#endif

#define FAIL() *failStream << ""

#include "FailureReporter.hpp"

TEST(FailureReporterTest, failMethod) {
    const char* errorMessage = "Test error message";
    FailureReporter *reporter;
    std::stringstream stream;

    failStream = &stream;

    reporter = new FailureReporter();

    reporter->fail(errorMessage);

    EXPECT_STREQ(errorMessage, stream.str().c_str());

    delete reporter;
}
```

MockFailureReporter.cpp

```
#ifndef MOCK_FAILURE_REPORTER_HPP
#define MOCK_FAILURE_REPORTER_HPP

#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "FailureReporter.hpp"

class MockFailureReporter : public FailureReporter {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(fail, void(const char*));
};

#endif
```

DummyTest.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "MockFailureReporter.hpp"

TEST(DummyTest, dummy) {
    new MockFailureReporter();
    SUCCEED();
}
```

Compiling the sources with

```
g++ -c DummyTest.cpp
g++ -c FailureReporterTest.cpp
```

and linking them with

```
g++ DummyTest.o FailureReporterTest.o -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -lgmock_main
```

generates an a.out executable that fails the failMethod test, while linking them with

```
g++ FailureReporterTest.o DummyTest.o -pthread -lgtest -lgmock -lgmock_main
```

generates an a.out executable that succeeds both tests. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FailureReporter {
public:
  virtual void fail(const char* errorMessage) {
    /* code */
```

creates an implicitly `inline` implementation of `FailureReporter::fail`.

`inline` functions are exported.  If the linker sees two `inline` functions of the same name and type, it will silently discard one.  If they are not actually identical, then your program is ill formed, and no diagnostic is required.

When you redefine `FAIL()` in only one compilation unit and link it with others, you end up with two definitions of `FailureReporter::fail`.  They link, and undefined behaviour results.  In your case, you get one of them running in both cases, determined bu whatever arbitrary rule the linker chose to discard inline collisions.  Which looks like 'keep first one I see'.